# Trying to configure prometheus with alert manager but getting error with rules file

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

In my prometheus.yml,the rules file is called rules.yml and it has this

```
---
groups:
  - name: example
    rules:
      - alert: ServiceDown
        expr: up == 0
        for: 2m
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: cannot connect to {{ $labels.job }}
```

when i run sudo ./promtool check config rules.yml i get the error

```
Checking rules.yml
  FAILED: parsing YAML file rules.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 2: field groups not found in type config.plain
```

I am not sure what is wrong as i am following this https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/

Prometheus version is 2.18.1

Hoping for some assistance from someone

Thanks
KK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading the rules.yml using the "rule_file" clause in the Prometheus configuration file, right?

```
rule_files:
  - rules.yml
```

I notice that we can't execute the "promtool check config" directly to the rule file but if you execute it to the Prometheus configuration file it'll check the rule file correctly:

```
$ promtool check config prometheus.yaml

Checking prometheus.yaml
  SUCCESS: 1 rule files found

Checking rules.yaml
  SUCCESS: 18 rules found
```

Comment: Yes i am using rules.yml using the rule_file clause. Thank you very much I would like to accept  your answer as this is correct and thank you for your reply much appreciated