# What should be the correct rule to specify in alert_rules.yml file in prometheus

Tags: linux, yaml, alert, prometheus, yaml-cpp

Below is the yam file i am currently using.

```
groups:
 - name: alertname
   rules:
   - alert: InstanceDown
     expr: up == 0
     for: 1m
```

Below is the error I got after passing it through the prom tool in Prometheus.

```
Checking alert_rules.yml
  FAILED: unknown fields in config: groups
```

I am unable to find any solution to it as I have checked on the internet and it is showing a valid yml file.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the alert_rules.yml file using the "rule_file" clause in the Prometheus configuration file, right?

If yes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058871/trying-to-configure-prometheus-with-alert-manager-but-getting-error-with-rules-f/62068105#62068105).